# The conjecture $A159634(n) = \psi(2n)/3$ where $\psi$ is the Dedekind psi function.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Steven Finch is the author of the OEIS-sequence [A159634](http://oeis.org/A159634) which is defined as

> "Coefficient for dimensions of spaces of modular & cusp forms of weight $k/2$, level $4n$ >and trivial character, where $k \ge 5$ is odd."

Recently Enrique Pérez Herrero conjectured that this sequence is given by $\psi(2n)/3$ where $\psi(n)$ is the Dedekind psi function:

$$ A159634(n) = \psi(2n)/3 $$

Finch refers to a paper of H. Cohen and J. Oesterle, "Dimensions des espaces de formes modulaires, Modular Functions of One Variable."
Can someone shed some light on this conjecture or prove / disprove it?

Comment: What does "coefficient for dimensions" mean?

Comment: This question was also posed on MathOverflow. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161948